# ReplaceAll to clean string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, str-replace, replaceall

I have to clean my data using few `replaceAll` function.

```
JSON.parse(data.replaceAll('{\'', '{"').replaceAll('\'}', '"}').replaceAll('\',\'', '","').replaceAll('\': \'', '": "').replace(/[\n\r]+/g, ' ').replaceAll("  ", " "));
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "clean" your data.  What is an example input/output format you would like to see.

Comment: Is there a order for replacing. When replacing with above code it will be replaced, already replaced characters too.

Comment: Consider using a library like [JSON5](https://json5.org) to parse your non-standard JSON input. Writing your own like this is likely going to end up with a edge failure case.

Comment: Where does `replaceAll()` come from? That's not a native method

Comment: @charlietfl probably using a polyfill for [`String.prototype.replaceAll` proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-replaceall)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could clean up the code and define your replacements in an array of pairs and iterate through it using `reduce`

```js
const replacements = [["{'", '{"'], ["'}", '"}'], ["','", '","'], ["': '", '": "'], ['\n', ' '], ['\r', ' '], ['  ', ' ']];

const data = `{' {'{'{' {' '}'} '}'}  ','',' ',' ': ' ': '': '': '             Hello\n\r\n\n\r\n\n\r\nWorld\n\r`;

const newData = replacements.reduce((a, [token, replacement]) => a.replace(new RegExp(token, 'g'), replacement), data);

console.log(newData);
```

But as mentioned by Dean Taylor it's best to use a library to parse non-standard JSON data (if that is what you're trying to do).